# How to install Sass in brackets text editor

Tags: sass, adobe-brackets

**Duplicate Question?**

Yes it is. But a little bit different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103570/how-to-use-sass-in-brackets-text-editor)

**Overview:**

I am also a new user of the brackets text editor. I know the difference between Scss & Sass. But the reason why I am using brackets text editor is for just Sass not Scss.

I saw some tutorials of [Jason Sanjose](https://github.com/jasonsanjose) for integrating Sass in brackets text editor. But I think. I am not doing it right. Below is my steps. What I am doing.

- Install Sass for bracket using Extension Manager.
- Install bower and bourbon
- Create folder on root named: "SASS" and inside this folder create app.sass file.
- Create folder on root named: "CSS"
- Create a config file named: ".brackets.json" and put below code inside it:

  ```
  {
    "sass.enabled": false,
    "path": {
              "SASS/app.scss": {
              "sass.enabled": true,
              "sass.options": {
              "outputDir": "../CSS/",
              "includePaths": [],
              "sourceComments": true,
              "outputStyle": "nested"
            }
         }
      }
  }
  ```

  and here is the snapshot also [image: reference]

**Question:**

When I write below code in app.sass file it is not converting it to css file or creating any css file in output directory.

```
body
    background-color: black
```

Now my question is: Please explain me how I convert sass file in css or tell me what I am doing wrong in ".brackets.json" file or in my "app.sass" file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot searching on web. I found a useful article and my answer. Which I am sharing with you guys.

**Brackets-SASS Plugin setup**
[Step By Step Tutorial](http://harikrishkk.blogspot.com/2016/01/brackets-sass-plugin-setup.html) Without migrating on other apps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install Sass in you text editor mate,only thing you need to install on your computer is [Prepros](http://prepros.io),that software support sass/scss coffeescript typescript FTP upload and much more

Comment: How we can do this using brackets texteditor? why I need to install Prepros?

Comment: Like i said,Prepro is a compile software come with awesome features,and you just need to click the sass file and tell him where to compile to css,and click the live preview button,than you are good to go,and using the fave brackets texteditor

Comment: You means in brackets there is no ability to transpile sass into css? Right?

Comment: Em i thank you can install package at brackets,before i use Atom i will install sass(compile),coffeescript(compile),livereload,etc package,but when i got Prepros install,it really change the way i code,it make life more easily,and i believe some of the package at Atom will be showing at brackets,but i'm sure i'm true or not,but if you got time,try out Prepros.

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend installing Koala.app - it's fully automated and refreshes on save.

Text editors *can* come pre-packaged or with an addon that **highlights** SASS and SCSS, but all (which I know of) cannot compile it.