# Sass is not working in Brackets IDE

Tags: html, sass

I installed ruby on windows using ruby installer and then installed sass using ruby's command prompt.

```
gem install sass
```

its shows installed successfully.and then i tried to add one main.scss file but its not working.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.scss">
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

main.scss

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

Comment: I make an edit in your question. Now your question is more clear from previous.

Answer (score 0):

You need Brackets IDE to working with Sass. Kindly see my [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249787/how-to-install-sass-in-brackets-text-editor/38301903#38301903) for further help.

Comment: Yes i am working with Brackets IDE and installed Brackets SASS plugin...But not working

Comment: Dear see my question its help me and Sass is working for me. May be you missing something. You need proper step by step tutorial which you will see in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) You still need to include the css file, not the scss in your index.html

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

2) This is an example brackets.json to let your IDE know about a main.scss file that will compile to `../css/main.css` relative to your source file:

```
{
    "sass.enabled": false,
    "sass.compiler": "libsass",
    "path": {
        "scss/styles.scss": {
            "sass.enabled": true, 
            "sass.options": {                
                "outputDir": "../css/",
                "imagePath": null,
                "sourceComments": false,
                "outputStyle": "nested"
            },
            "linting.collapsed": true
        }
    }
}
```