# Brackets SCSS file to CSS file

Tags: css, sass, adobe-brackets, file-watcher

When I was studying Multimedia I got a free copy of PhpStorm.
Using PhpStorm I managed to some techincal magic using Ruby(I can't exactly remember how it worked) to write code in SCSS and phpstorm would automatically create a new file and compile all my code to usable CSS code.

I believe I remember something about a 'filewatcher' but im not sure.

**Is there any way to do the same in Brackets**?

maybe an addon to Brackets or something?

Thanks

Comment: Install an extension, there's one called Brackets SASS.

Comment: Retracted my original close vote in lieu of duplicate : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249787/how-to-install-sass-in-brackets-text-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249787/how-to-install-sass-in-brackets-text-editor), also a quick google could solve this with other related articles etc. Cheers!

Comment: FYI, the Ruby version of SASS is basically [abandoned](https://sass-lang.com/ruby-sass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're talking about compilers that translate SCSS into CSS ([and their integration in PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html)).

So maybe you will be interested in [Brackets-SASS Plugin](http://harikrishkk.blogspot.com/2016/01/brackets-sass-plugin-setup.html).